# Redundant RelativeLayout, how to estimate effects

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Greatings, All. 
I have a layout.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/editor_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/contentViewBG" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/setting_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spen_setting_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spen_setting_margin"
            android:background="#00000000" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/scoreboard"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:background="#ffffff"
           android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It raises questions to me:

1. @+id/editor_area, is it totally redundant, except of course the
   background line which I can move one level up in
   @+id/editor?
2. Assuming I have only few UIx in all the children layouts, and
   just draw in the canvas_container, what's the estimate for a
   "redundant" @+id/editor_area wrapping around them?
3. Continuing #2 above, what if I have 4-5 buttons in the @+id/scoreboard?

As the questions speak for themselves, I'm a newbie in this. Any suggestions are most welcomed.

Comment: have you tried playing around in the simulator to see the effects of changing these things?

Comment: It wouldn't help? given the nature of the Eclipse emulator. I tried on a device, but doesn't see any difference, of course.

Comment: Oh, yes. Just hit me that I may use the Hierarchy Viewer, but then I will have to use the emulator as it doesn't run on device. Tks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. in the current layout it's redundant, but if you may add some more view in, it may not.

2&3. not clear what's your question, are you asking about efficiency?

IMO, the best way to solve questions regarding UI is to try yourself.

Best Regards

Comment: Please clarify on #1: any view to add can be done directly inside @+id/editor, i.e. we can do without @+id/editor_area? But, I do plan to <include> ...some menu_bar...<include/> either inside editor or editor_area, any difference then?

Comment: #2 & #3 are based on that @+id/editor really is redundant, does it matter? in what situations (i.e. #2 and #3). Thanks.